# Conditional Regexp: return only one group

Tags: regex

Two types of URLs I want to match:

```
(1) www.test.de/type1/12345/this-is-a-title.html
(2) www.test.de/category/another-title-oh-yes.html
```

In the first type, I want to match "12345".
In the second type I want to match "category/another-title-oh-yes".

Here is what I came up with:

```
(?:(?:\.de\/type1\/([\d]*)\/)|\.de\/([\S]+)\.html)
```

This returns the following:

For type (1):

```
Match group 1: 12345
Match group 2:
```

For type (2):

```
Match group: 
Match group 2: category/another-title-oh-yes
```

As you can see, it is working pretty well already.
For various reasons I need the regex to return only one match-group, though. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: you can concatenate the 2 matched strings together as at least 1 is always empty in your regex..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Java/PHP/Python

Get both the matched group at index 1 using both *Negative Lookahead* and *Positive Lookbehind*.

```
((?<=\.de\/type1\/)\d+|(?<=\.de\/)(?!type1)[^\.]+)
```

There are two regex pattern that are ORed.

First regex pattern looks for `12345`

Second regex pattern looks for `category/another-title-oh-yes`.

---

*Note:*

- Each regex pattern must match exactly one match in each URL
- Combine whole regex pattern inside the parenthesis `(...|...)` and remove parenthesis from the `[^\.]+` and `\d+` where:

  ```
  [^\.]+   find anything until dot is found
  \d+      find one or more digits
  ```

Here is online demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/pX5sD5/3)

---

Input:

```
www.test.de/type1/12345/this-is-a-title.html
www.test.de/category/another-title-oh-yes.html
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [18-23] `12345`
MATCH 2
1.  [57-86] `category/another-title-oh-yes`
```

---

#### JavaScript

try this one and get both the matched group at index 2.

```
((?:\.de\/type1\/)(\d+)|(?:\.de\/)(?!type1)([^\.]+))
```

Here is online demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/pX5sD5/4).

Input:

```
www.test.de/type1/12345/this-is-a-title.html
www.test.de/category/another-title-oh-yes.html
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  `.de/type1/12345`
2.  `12345`
MATCH 2
1.  `.de/category/another-title-oh-yes`
2.  `category/another-title-oh-yes`
```

Comment: This works amazingly well, didn't even know stuff like this was possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
^www\.test\.de/(type1/(.*)\.|(.*)\.html)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GghMLomjsOXBTdHy)

Then for example:

```
var str = "www.test.de/type1/12345/this-is-a-title.html"
var regex = /^www\.test\.de/(type1/(.*)\.|(.*)\.html)$/
console.log(str.match(regex))
```

This will output an array, the first element is the string, the second one is whatever is after the website address, the third is what matched according to type1 and the fourth element is the rest.

You can do something like `var matches = str.match(regex); return matches[2] || matches[3];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this returns three groups of matches, whereas I really just needed on matched group (because I don't have access to the code behind it).